# BraintreeError HOSTED_FIELDS_FIELDS_EMPTY despite non empty values

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

If I look inside `hostedFieldsInstance._state.fields.number.container.value` I can see that the value is not empty.

However when I do:

```
hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
```

I get the following error:

```
i {name: "BraintreeError", code: "HOSTED_FIELDS_FIELDS_EMPTY",         message: "All fields are empty. Cannot tokenize empty card fields.", type: "CUSTOMER", details: undefined}
```

Comment: If this is still occurring, can you provide more code for your Hosted Fields (the form, the JS, etc.)? It may also be worth reaching out to [Braintree's Support Team](https://help.braintreepayments.com).

Comment: @David no I figured it out it was because I used inputs instead of divs as in the example however I do not know why the example didn't work...

Comment: Nice find! That's odd that there's an example out there using inputs. Do you remember where you saw that?

Comment: @David Could you explain how changing inputs to divs solved your issue? Didn't understand the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out it was because I used inputs instead of divs as in the example however I do not know how the example did work

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by " I used inputs instead of divs"? I'm having the same issue and don't quite understand your answer :(

Comment: @UndercoverCoder sry for the late reply, the example that I have copied from in that case contained an HTML structure that used inputs instead of divs to represent the inputs. In the proper working example divs are used to represent the inputs.